# handling a controller in spring

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I'm working on a web application but it seems have a problem but I can't figure it out whats wrong, and yes there are so many questions asked about this but none of them haved helped me..

I'm using ajax to get some information then I'm trying to pass it to a controller, here is my problem: It seems never get to the controller but I'm not sure what's the problem, also when I try to use the tag's mvc annotation driven it shows me an error, the ajax looks fine. I'm quite sure my problem is the controller or the way I'm calling it or passing the data.

I'll attach some images  to show the error it shows up and the files I'm using.

[image: ajax_request]

[image: controller]

[image: error_when_i_place_tags]

Comment: Hello, just a friendly FYI.  Most contributors of this community hate images.  Post the actual code versus images.

Comment: is your controller running?

Comment: your method is mapped with `/login` and you are calling it with `login.htm`. Also by default methods are of type `GET`. Make it a `POST` method since your ajax call is of type `POST`

Comment: thanks for the info @Mister Positive,

Comment: @RequestMapping(value = {"/login.htm"}, method = {org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod.POST}) something like this ? @Adbullah Wasi

Comment: for  mvc annotation driven if  you have the prefix in the xml it should work . the main thing is jackson jar check whether you have included it .